# My app was rejected for missing restore button

Tags: ios8

They given reason  :

> To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be
>   appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore
>   process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user.

I am using In app purchase in my app, and alsoI have using This method :

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
- (void) paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

How to solve restore button issue ?

Comment: What are you actually asking...how to add a button?

Comment: Please go through the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9). It states that you **must** provide a restore button (like Restore Purchases, Restore Subscription, etc) so that the user can restore their purchase if they have, in fact, already purchased the consumable/non-consumable in question. Failing which your app **will** be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a "Restore" button as well, and it should be easily visible to the user so that when user clicks it, it restores the purchase using `restoreCompletedTransactions`